Laravel 11: job rate limit to not exceed rate limit of external API
since Laravel 11 queues can also have a rate limit now (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#rate-limiting). My Laravel application is doing some requests to the Shopify API to fetch new products, add notes to some orders and also adding shipment information such as a tracking number to the order.
I have a Shopify Basic plan which is allowed to make a max of 2 requests per second but no more than 40 requests per minute.
Now I want to write a universal job which I can utilize to make calls to the Shopify API. So either I am fetching products or updating products, I want to have one single job class which takes care of that, so I can make sure I am not exceeding the Shopify API rate limit.
However, I am not able to make this work. I have defined a rate limit in my AppServiceProvider.php as described in the Laravel documentation:
public function boot(): void
{
    // Rate limit Shopify API requests set to 2 per second and 40 per minute
    RateLimiter::for('shopify-api-requests', function (object $job) {
        return [
            Limit::perSecond(2),
            Limit::perMinute(40),
        ];
    });
}

This is my reusable job class, which I want to reuse for every request I make to the Shopify API:
class ShopifyApiRequestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $endpoint;
    public $method;
    public $data;
    
    public function __construct(string $endpoint, string $method = 'GET', array $data = null)
    {
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    
    public function backoff(): array
    {
        return [1, 5, 10];
    }
    
    public function tries(): int
    {
        return 3;
    }
    
    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            new RateLimited('shopify-api-requests'),
            //new WithoutOverlapping('shopify-api-requests')
        ];
    }
    
    public function handle()
    {
        // Construct the full URL
        $url = 'https://' . config('settings.SHOPIFY_API_DOMAIN') . '/admin/api/' . config('settings.SHOPIFY_API_VERSION') . '/' . $this->endpoint;

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => config('settings.SHOPIFY_API_KEY'),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->{$this->method}($url, $this->data);

        // Handle the response as needed (e.g., log it, store it, etc.)
        if ($response->failed()) {
            // Handle failure (e.g., retry the job, log the error, etc.)
            Log::error("Shopify API Request Failed (" . $response->status() . "): " . $response->body() . " " . $url);
        } else {
            // Handle success (e.g., process the response, store it, etc.)
            Log::info("Shopify API Request Successful");
        }
    }
}

When I test my job class, it does not behave as expected. I have created a foreach loop and have dispatched my job 10 times.
The expected result I am trying to archive is that every job which got dispatched is not overlapping with another job of that same class (ShopifyApiRequestJob) and per second are only 2 jobs being processed max and per minute 30 jobs max.
However, I end up with a log like this:
[2024-08-24 19:29:11] local.INFO: Shopify API Request Successful  
[2024-08-24 19:29:17] local.INFO: Shopify API Request Successful  
[2024-08-24 19:29:20] local.INFO: Shopify API Request Successful  
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]
[2024-08-24 19:29:26] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ShopifyApiRequestJob has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): [...]

Three jobs are being processed sucessfully but all other 7 jobs fail because of MaxAttemptsExceededException. I have increased the $backOff time on purpose to debug it but was not successful.
I don't understand what I did wrong, configuring my job. I have followed the documentation.
Anybody can give me an advice on how to solve this problem?
Furthermore, I would like to receive a notification if all retries of a job have failed and not for every retry.
Anybody knows how to archive this behavior?
Kind regards

I'm confused, I can't see any perSecond method in the Limit class, and in my tests I get an exception undefined method?

I've faced similar issue related to Rate Limit with external API.
Can you remove tries method and add retryUntil method
public function retryUntil(): \DateTime
{
    return now()->addMinutes(Illuminate\Support\Carbon::MINUTES_PER_HOUR * 2);
}

Here is the My Job implementation
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Report\PrtgReport;

use App\Models\User;
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\WithoutOverlapping;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class SendExternalRequest implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Batchable;
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 120;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $response = Http::baseUrl('mybaseurl.com')
            ->get('test.php', []);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            //logic Goes here

        } else {
            $this->release(10);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the middleware the job should pass through.
     *
     * @return array<int, object>
     */
    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            new APIRateLimiterMiddleware(),

            (new WithoutOverlapping(User::class.':HIT:'.$this->user->id))
                ->releaseAfter(10),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine the time at which the job should timeout.
     */
    public function retryUntil(): DateTime
    {
        return now()->addMinutes(Carbon::MINUTES_PER_HOUR * 2);
    }
}

And Here is the middleware that I use
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class APIRateLimiterMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Process the queued job.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(object): void  $next
     */
    public function handle(object $job, Closure $next): void
    {
        Redis::throttle('API'.':Screenshot')
            ->block(0)
            ->allow(1)
            ->every(3) // Allow 1 job every 3 seconds
            ->then(function () use ($job, $next) {
                // Lock obtained...
                $next($job);
            }, function () use ($job) {
                // Could not obtain lock...
                $job->release(3); // Release the job back to the queue after 3 seconds
            });
    }
}


The code I've Provided is just a sample from my implementation pls
make sure to adjust to your requirements.


Thank you for your answer! This does work for me. I just have one question. When the requests fail, you tell your job $this->release(10);. Does this mean the job gets queued again and tries again till the defined retryUntil and if the requests still fail than the job is being marked as failed and not being put back to the queue?

That will release the job back to the queue with 10 seconds delay. Please refer to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#manually-releasing-a-job
